# Embedding a Java application packaged as a jlink image in a macOS app

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jlink

I am trying to embed a Java application into a native Mac app. The Java application is packaged with jlink (Java 9+) including a stripped down JRE.

I'm trying to use the Java Invocation Interface to create the JVM and launch the main class, but the program crashes at the the point where `JNI_CreateJavaVM` is called, because it can't find `libjava.dylib`.

In my Xcode project, I have a "Copy Files" phase that copies the entire jlink image (the folder containing `bin`, `lib`, etc. directories) into the application bundle, into the `Contents/image` directory.

```
$ ls -l Java\ Native\ Wrapper.app/Contents/image/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  11 ahs  staff   352 Jan 13 12:46 bin
drwxr-xr-x   6 ahs  staff   192 Jan 13 12:46 conf
drwxr-xr-x  25 ahs  staff   800 Jan 13 12:46 legal
drwxr-xr-x  52 ahs  staff  1664 Jan 13 12:46 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 ahs  staff   717 Jan 13 12:46 release
```

The dylib file is there:

```
$ file Java\ Native\ Wrapper.app/Contents/image/lib/libjava.dylib 
Java Native Wrapper.app/Contents/image/lib/libjava.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

My Objective-C code links against the JNI library in `lib/jli/libjli.dylib`. Xcode automatically copies it into the Frameworks directory of the app bundle.

When I run the program, I get the following error on the console:

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

I added the `image/lib` directory to the runtime search path. Inspecting the binary with `otool` confirms it:

```
$ otool -l Java\ Native\ Wrapper
...
Load command 18
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path @executable_path/../Frameworks (offset 12)
Load command 19
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path @executable_path/../image/lib (offset 12)
...
```

I am really stumped here. I've tried copying the dylibs to the Frameworks directory, that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work just fine. If I create user specific variable - `JAVA_HOME` (`User-Defined Settings`) and set it such way it points to `jlink` based version of Java.

`JAVA_HOME`: `$(HOME)/tmp/jdk-13-stripped`

and then, I make sure to add: `$(JAVA_HOME)/jdk-13-stripped/lib` as a resource (it will end up inside `Resources` dir of the final application) and then, I set following settings:

```
Run Search Paths:     @executable_path/../Resources/lib/server
Header Search Paths:  $(JAVA_HOME)/include and $(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
Library Search Paths: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
Other Linker Flags:   -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
```

and then, I run the code

```
> ./CallJVM
Hello from Java
```

If I check which image was loaded, it is taken from the proper location

```
> lldb CallJVM
(lldb) image list
...
...
[  7] ....   .../Debug/CallJVM.app/Contents/Resources/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
```

**Update**

In case someone needs video tutorial related to this topic, here you go: [Embedding JVM inside macOS application bundle (using XCode)](https://youtu.be/-DwcxuWXIgI)

Comment: Thanks, that got me a bit further. I'm using the client JVM. I also had to "Disable Library Validation" under "Hardened Runtime", which I do not yet understand why (Code Signing with Apple Development Identity is configured on the Target). But I'm running into the next issue: The call to `JNI_CreateJavaVM` fails with an error:

Comment: And the error is: `Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space in CodeCache (160K)`
I'm not specifying any memory options. Any ideas what could have gone wrong here?

Comment: If I use the server VM, i get a different error: `Could not reserve enough space in CodeHeap 'non-nmethods' (2496K)`. Apparently this is related to hardened runtime, other people are experiencing this as well. If I disable the hardened runtime checks, it crashes with a segmentation fault. Oh well.
You wouldn't happen to have some working sample code lying around, would you?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo066 - this is `Makefile` based, pure stuff. It works just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I had entitlements for hardened runtime and ran the app directly, things started to work. Running the app in Xcode led to segmentation faults, as the mechanism is used by the JVM (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8182575). I had also had to create the JVM on a separate thread, as the application is a GUI application.

Comment: When it comes to debugging JNI code inside XCode, take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEA-3uI7Y18 and here: http://www.owsiak.org/running-jni-based-code-inside-xcode/ - you have to make sure to use `process handle --pass true --stop false --notify true SIGSEGV`, otherwise `lldb` will fail :( `gdb` handles this one a little bit better.